# mysql CREATE VIEW not working from mysql_query

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-view

I have a code to create VIEW in mysql database which is working fine on my local server.
It creates and crop view normally. But on my Online server it gives error

```
"CREATE VIEW command denied to user"
```

for online database I manually create VIEW in Database form PHPmyAdmin [Myadmin is in localhost online] it creating, SO i have permission to create VIEW on online database.

But with php `mysql_query` it is giving `command denied` error. is there any service to be on for creating view with php.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This message says that user doesn't have enough permissions to create view. Permissions are granted to particular user @ particular host. You must execute

```
GRANT CREATE VIEW ON *.* TO 'username'@'host';
```

where host is hostname from where your CREATE VIEW is executed

Also, user must have SELECT privilages on all tabels and columns involved

Comment: I give permission from cPanel, i can create view manually form myadmin but not from php code.

Comment: than I would expect that you connect with different users.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this from CPanel / phpMyAdmin web interface because my create script had the name of the database embedded in it that was not the same as my wordpress mysql database. I.e "CREATE VIEW `blog`.`vwMyView` ....".

I had a local MySql Database on my computer that was named `blog`, which was different than my WordPress MySQL database. So naturally it gives an security error instead of saying the database was invalid. Silly me for not catching it sooner.